# What is the name of the new url path prefix for website meta files?

Tags: url, path, metadata, rewriting

A while ago I saw a proposal for a new URL path prefix for website meta files - that is, instead of having everything at root level (like `/robots.txt` and `/favicon.ico`) there was a prefix to give `/__something_here__/metafilehere`

The idea being to give a single prefix to deal with when rewriting/etc for a whole bunch of new meta-files that would live within it (instead of at root level).

I cannot remember what the `__something_here__` part is anywhere, and nothing I search for is giving any hint of a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean `/.well-known/`.

[RFC 5785: Defining Well-Known Uniform Resource Identifiers (URIs)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5785):

> This memo defines a path prefix for "well-known locations", "/.well-known/", in selected Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) schemes.

Note that such well-known URIs have to be registered before you may use them. Proposals can be made [on the mailing list](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/wellknown-uri-review/current/maillist.html).

All registered well-known URIs are listed here:
http://www.iana.org/assignments/well-known-uris/

(As you’ll see, you can’t use it for your robots.txt or Favicon.)

Comment: That's the one. No need to add more or migrate the others - just wanted to exclude from rewrites and handle as a reserved/special name in situations where users can specify their own URL paths.